# Does the type of healing potion you give to the Wounded Guard have an effect on the game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-falskaar

Once you have encountered the Wounded Guard (which starts ['The Crusher's End' quest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmddk.jpg)), you can choose to give him a healing potion, from a potion of minor healing to a potion of ultimate healing.

[image: Wounded Guard]

Does the choice of healing potion (or not giving him a healing potion) have an effect on the game later on?

I've also noticed that [the Wounded Guard appears in the game later on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6zZL.jpg). (I gave him a potion of Ultimate Healing when I first saw him.) Does the choice of healing potion have an effect on that part?

Answer (score 2):

I've played Falsaar twice now with two different characters, and I've not noticed any effect on the type of healing potion you give the wounded guard (the first time was an extreme, the second an ultimate)

Comment: Did you see the wounded guard (now not wounded) again in a later mission that is part of the main quest? (Forgot the name of the quest, sorry.)